# how can I provide chat support in website

Tags: asp.net

I want to implement video and chat facility in my website 
can anyone tell what do I need to do
get api or service
which api/service is the best

Answer (score 1):

use jabber, Google is also use that for video and audio chat.

Comment: Most of company like AOL also use this protocol for messenger.vote me up if possible.